# Alt+F2 command output

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I ran a command using Alt+F2  .

I then realised that the command would have output something important to standard output and/or standard error.

Is there a way to display the output of that command? (Is it logged somewhere? Is there a way to get a hidden window that contains the output of all commands launched via Alt+F2? Or is it too late?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command already finished, it's output is lost.

In older GNOME versions, there was a checkbox "Run in terminal" in the Alt+F2 dialog. Ticking this checkbox causes a terminal window to open while the command is running, that will display the command output.

This is still available in GNOME Flashback desktop (which I use), but no more in GNOME Shell. But even in GNOME Flashback, the terminal window closes right after the command finishes, so it's of little use.

It seems that you have to use Ctrl+Alt+T instead of Alt+F2, to open the terminal window first and then run the command from the terminal.

Comment: I don't have such a checkbox. Just the title "Run a Command", below a textfield, and below a text: "Press ESC to close". That's all. Gnome version 3.36.8 (according to Settings app), `gnome-shell --version` 3.36.4

Comment: Hm... did they remove this in GNOME Shell? Strange. I use GNOME Flashback and the option is still there. However - as I just checked - the terminal disappears right after the command finishes, so it's of little use as well. Looks like they messed it up since I last used it :(

Comment: raj, better edit your answer to fully correct it, instead of having this "Edit" section. Please attempt to directly render the correct answer, and adapt the answer fully if new insight requires corrections. Otherwise it becomes confusing and inconcise.